# WinDbg psscor4 !ASPXPages -ip not listing anything

Tags: windbg

I'm analyzing a dump file taken with procdump -ma w3wp on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine running .NET 4.

```
 !ASPXPages –ip 
 Going to dump the HttpContexts found in the heap.
 HttpContext    Client IP            Server IP         ThreadId
 Total 42 HttpContext objects
```

This command output list just the headers and no values compared to !ASPXPages which fills in the normal output (but no IP's).  Any ideas why this is happening on my dump file?